# I can't set "options" property of my select class, after I fetching it. It's empty

Tags: reactjs

I have a list and I want to filter it by language. I fetched the list of languages from backend, and it works, and I wanted to populate a select with it. But when I want to set the list of languages as property to a react Select class, it stays as an empty list, as I set it in the constructor

```
class Informations extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            languages: [], //the list has this value in LanguageSelect
            selectedLanguage: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {     
        getLanguages().then(response => {
            this.setState({ languages: response });
        })
        //after this, the value of this.state.languages changed
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <LanguageSelect options={this.state.languages}>
                {/*here I add an options property with the list*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class LanguageSelect extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { langs: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ langs:this.props.options });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                {this.state.langs.map((prop, key) => {
                  return (<option key={key}>{prop}</option>);
                })}
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `getLanguage` returns?

Comment: `function getLanguages() {
    return fetch('informations/languages', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));
}`

Comment: returns this fetch call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to store options to the local state in LanguageSelect. As they are passed as props you should use them directly. At the time of mount that data is not available and thats why its empty

```
class LanguageSelect extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { langs: [] };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <select onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
            {this.props.options.map((prop, key) => {
              return (<option key={key}>{prop}</option>);
            })}
        </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @varoons What's the point of calling `componentDidMount()` if it's not doing anything?